# Using SQL to Split Multiple Date Ranges Into Unique and All-Inclusive Ranges

Tags: sql, date

I need an efficient way to break up date spans that overlap and have gaps into distinct non-overlapping spans that cover the entire time frame. Every day must be accounted for in one and only one date range.

To make it easier to visualize, I am using integers instead of dates. I am using Oracle 19c.

Consider the following data:

```
Create table time_span_test (
    C_ID varchar2(10),
    ID_TYPE varchar2(10), 
    SPAN_START int,
    SPAN_END int
);

insert into time_span_test values ('1','WA',1,100);
insert into time_span_test values ('A','EWH',5,20);
insert into time_span_test values ('B','EWH',25,50);
insert into time_span_test values ('C','EWH',45,75);
insert into time_span_test values ('D','EWH',75,76);
insert into time_span_test values ('E','EWH',76,105);
```

Ulimately, I need a table that looks something like the following:

| Start | End | IDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 20 | 1, A |
| 21 | 24 | 1 |
| 25 | 44 | 1, B |
| 45 | 50 | 1, C |
| 51 | 74 | 1, C |
| 75 | 75 | 1, C, D |
| 76 | 76 | 1, D, E |
| 77 | 100 | 1, E |
| 101 | 105 | E |

The key here is that all the time in the spans is covered and that there are no overlapping days. So if you join on to this table a specific day, it will retrieve only one record.

One Note: I know I could use a table with each day from the min(start) to the max(end) and then group by the different ID's to collapse it back down. I am looking for a more efficient method (though if you think that would be the most efficient method, I'd be interested to hear about that).

Comment: Is it just my perception gone wonky, or is everyone asking about overlapping date records today?

Comment: Your final para is probably what I'd do, btw - it's an easy to understand approach.. What's the use pattern for this data? How many thousand times an hour do you need to query it? How often will it change/are new ranges added? There are a lot of factors/engineering decisions behind "most efficient"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Your right there are a lot of factors but the date spans can be several years and only have one or two date spans between them. So what could be 2 rows could turn into hundreds or thousands pretty quickly.

Comment: Can you choose a standard time unit, for example a week or a month, such that your data is divided into a manageable number of regular sized blocks? If not what criteria will decide how you cut?